# Using Python to Input BLS API Data into Microsoft Excel

Tags: python, json, excel

First off, thank you for helping. I am very new at posting questions on stackoverflow. Please let me know if I made it too confusing or didn't follow an efficient format.

I started by using the example Python code on the BLS website, but it doesn't work when I try to run it. It is the code below.

```
import requests
import json
import prettytable
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
data = json.dumps({"seriesid": ['CUUR0000SA0','SUUR0000SA0'],"startyear":"2011", "endyear":"2014"})
p = requests.post('http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/', data=data, headers=headers)
json_data = json.loads(p.text)
for series in json_data['Results']['series']:
x=prettytable.PrettyTable(["series id","year","period","value","footnotes"])
seriesId = series['seriesID']
for item in series['data']:
    year = item['year']
    period = item['period']
    value = item['value']
    footnotes=""
    for footnote in item['footnotes']:
        if footnote:
            footnotes = footnotes + footnote['text'] + ','
    'if 'M01' <= period <= 'M12':'
        x.add_row([seriesId,year,period,value,footnotes[0:-1]])
output = open(&quot;c:\\temp\\&quot; + seriesId + &quot;.txt&quot;,&quot;w&quot;)
output.write (x.get_string())
output.close()
```

It gives the following error.

```
  File "C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\Website\Python\BLS Second.py", line 20
    'if 'M01' <= period <= 'M12':'
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

After that I modified it to the code below, so that I could at least retrieve data.

```
 import json
 import prettytable
 import xlwt
 import requests
 headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
 data = json.dumps({"seriesid": ["LAUDV061124400000003"], "startyear": "2010", "endyear": "2015"})
 p = requests.post("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/"data = data, headers = headers)
 json_data = json.loads(p.text)
```

Then I tried to put that result into an Excel spreadsheet using:

```
workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet1 = workbook.add_sheet("Python Sheet1")

sheet1.write(0,0,p.text)

workbook.save("Pythonspreadsheet1.xls")

print ("Workbook Created")
```

It works, but it places all of the JSON below into one cell.

{"status":"REQUEST_SUCCEEDED","responseTime":321,"message":[],"Results":{
"series":
[{"seriesID":"LAUDV061124400000003","data":[{"year":"2014","period":"M12","periodName":"December","value":"4.6","footnotes":[{"code":"R","text":"Data were subject to revision on April 15, 2016."}]}, {"year":"2014","period":"M11","periodName":"November","value":"5.1","footnotes":[{"code":"R","text":"Data were subject to revision on April 15, 2016."}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M10","periodName":"October","value":"5.2","footnotes":[{"code":"R","text":"Data were subject to revision on April 15, 2016."}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M09","periodName":"September","value":"5.2","footnotes":[{"code":"R","text":"Data were subject to revision on April 15, 2016."}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M08","periodName":"August","value":"5.8","footnotes":[{"code":"R","text":"Data were subject to revision on April 15,

How do I split the data up to have separate columns featuring Year, periodName, and Value data without all of the JSON brackets and quotes?

I want it to look like the below in Excel with each piece of data in its own cell:

```
Year periodName  Value

2014 January    254.3
2014 February   356.8
2014 March      456.5
2014 April      422.3
2014 May        415.8
```

Thank you again for helping.

Comment: this line `sheet1.write(0,0,p.text)` says "Write all my data into cell 0,0 of sheet 1" ...

Comment: Thank you for the response. How do I split the JSON data into different cells?

Comment: I understand that a significant percentage of people who work with data these days are not programmers, but if you're going to use a programming language as a tool, it's highly beneficial *for you* if you at least learn enough of how to use that tool that you can recognize and fix a simple syntax error like the one in your first example. And you should pick the right tools. For what you are trying to do, you should be looking at things like [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which includes easy-to-use facilities for importing JSON and generating spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a fully reproducible example of how to get data from the Bureau of Labor Statistics ([BLS](https://www.bls.gov/)) API. Their Documentation ([link here](https://www.bls.gov/developers/api_python.htm))  provides an example of how to get data from the API using python.

In my code below, I create a dataframe using a function where I also add try and except clauses to raise an exception if the user exceeds the number of daily hits to the BLS API (Unregistered users may request up to 25 queries daily - [per documentation FAQs](https://www.bls.gov/developers/api_faqs.htm#signatures4)). Finally, using `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel()` I create an excel file.

I use the OP's BLS series and start year for my example.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests

def get_bls_data(series, start, end):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    data = json.dumps({"seriesid": series,"startyear":"%d" % (start), "endyear":"%d" % (end)})
    p = requests.post('https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/', data=data, headers=headers)
    json_data = json.loads(p.text)
    try:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        for series in json_data['Results']['series']:
            df_initial = pd.DataFrame(series)
            series_col = df_initial['seriesID'][0]
            for i in range(0, len(df_initial) - 1):
                df_row = pd.DataFrame(df_initial['data'][i])
                df_row['seriesID'] = series_col
                if 'code' not in str(df_row['footnotes']): 
                    df_row['footnotes'] = ''
                else:
                    df_row['footnotes'] = str(df_row['footnotes']).split("'code': '",1)[1][:1]
                df = df.append(df_row, ignore_index=True)
        return df
    except:
        json_data['status'] == 'REQUEST_NOT_PROCESSED'
        print('BLS API has given the following Response:', json_data['status'])
        print('Reason:', json_data['message'])


start = 2014
end = 2018
series = ['LAUDV061124400000003']

df = get_bls_data(series=series, start=start, end=end)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('bls.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'strings_to_numbers': True})
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Expected Output of bls.xlsx:

[image: Expected Output of bls.xlsx]